# ASP.Net (2.2) WebApp Connecting to Azure B2C Failure

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, web-applications, azure-ad-b2c

I have everything set up and tried this example:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnetcore-webapp/an-aspnet-core-web-app-with-azure-ad-b2c/

When i run it with the default fabrikam setup, it allows me to sign in and everything is fine. When i change the details to match my setup (which is working on my mobile app) it stops working. As soon as I click on Sign in on the example page, i get an error404

```
n unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found).
System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()

IOException: IDX20804: Unable to retrieve document from: '[PII is hidden]'.
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever.GetDocumentAsync(string address, CancellationToken cancel) in HttpDocumentRetriever.cs, line 96

InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: '[PII is hidden]'.
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager<T>.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken cancel) in ConfigurationManager.cs, line 202
```

I am not really sure whats happening. Is this something wrong in my B2C setup?
Is this because my API that its targetting (the REST api app which is protected by B2C) is using framework 3.1 and this app is on 2.2? does that matter?

If it is because of that, does anyone have a working example of how to do this on net 3.1? I started off with that, but I was never able to get anything working - i just hit endless errors, and couldnt find a working example on 3.1 so I just used this one from MS docs and stuck with 2.2

All i want here is to be able to get an access token from B2C that i can pass to the headers of an HttpClient so i can make requests to my REST api. SO if there is a different way to go about this im open to that too.

**note** I didnt post code, as the link above is the exact code im using, other than my tenant info being subbed out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue... somehow I missed updating the file AzureADB2COptions

```
public AzureAdB2COptions()
{
    AzureAdB2CInstance = "https://<tenant>.b2clogin.com/tfp";
}
```

I didn't update this to my tenant